# Retrieve property 'x' of all objects inside property 'y' with recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, oop, recursion, hierarchy

Consider the following example:

```
<script>
var McDuffFamily = {
    name: "Jack McDuff I",
    children: [
        {
            name:"Jack McDuff II",
            children: [
                {
                    name:"Jack McDuff III",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name:"Jack McDuff IV"
                        },
                        {
                            name:"Jonh McDuff I",
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name:"Jonh McDuff I",
                                    children: []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name:"Shena McDuff"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name:"Poor bastard",
            children: [
                {
                    name:"Citzen I",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name:"Darth Vader"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name:"Citzen II",
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
</script>
```

Is there any painless way to retrieve the names of all "Jack McDuff I" descendents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using recursion:

```
var tree =[McDuffFamily];
var kids = [];
for (i=0; i < tree.length; i++) {

   tree[i] && tree.push.apply(tree, tree[i].childrens)
   kids.push(tree[i]);
}
kids; // all children
```

Breakdown of the weird part:

```
tree[i] && tree.push.apply(tree, tree[i].childrens);
```

`tree[i] &&` is used with [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) ensuring that `tree[i]` is not null when I call `tree[i].children`

`tree.push.apply(tree, tree[i].childrens);` using [**apply**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which allows me to call a function, in this case [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), which takes any number of arguments on `tree`. So that line basically becomes `tree.push(child0, child1, ... childn);`.

so now `tree.length` has been increased by the number of children on the current child.

Comment: Looks interesting, but honestly, I don't quite understand how it works

Comment: Which part? I can shed some light on it if you want

Comment: tree[i] && tree.push.apply(tree, tree[i].childrens)

Comment: http://jsperf.com/push-apply-vs-recursion A bit slower, but this short-circuit evaluation and the push.apply stuff worth the answer

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to just use a basic recursive function:

```
function traverse(parent, visit) {
    var ii;

    visit(parent.name);

    for (ii = 0; ii < parent.children.length; ii += 1) {
        traverse(parent.children[ii], visit);
    }
}
```

Where the initial value of `parent` is `McDuffFamily` and `visit` is a function that does whatever you want to do when you visit a node.

Comment: The most fastest'n'clean solution here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This function will return all the descendants of a given name whitin the family tree:

```
function getDescendants(family, name)
{
     var result = [];

     var iterate = function(node, isDescendant)
     {
         if(isDescendant)
             result.push(node.name);
         else
             isDescendant = (node.name == name);

         for(var i=0; i<node.children.length; i++)
             iterate(node.children[i], isDescendant);
     };

     iterate(family, false);

     return result;
}
```

It will return an array that contains the names of all the descendants.

PS: I wrote `children` instead of `childrens`, since `children` is already plural.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var names = [], i = 0, l = McDuffFamily.childrens.length; i < l; i++) {
    names.push(McDuffFamily.childrens[i].name);
}

names; // ['Jack McDuff II', 'Poor bastard']
```

If you are using an environment (like Node or using MooTools) that allows for [].reduce you could also do:

```
names = McDuffFamily.childrens.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    prev.push(curr.name);
}, []);

names; // ['Jack McDuff II', 'Poor bastard']
```

I think [].reduce looks nicer, but it is more taxing

Comment: I believe he wanted the whole family tree not just Jack McDuff's Children. IE children of children.

Comment: Ah then my example is not quite there, eh